# localstack Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4566/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, localstack

I am trying to connect a aws s3 service from gitlab-ci script but I am keep on getting
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4566/". It looks like something has been changed in the latest image of the localstack as it was working fine before.

Below is the docker-compose file

```
localstack:
    container_name: config-localstack
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - '4566-4599:4566-4599'
    environment:
      SERVICES: s3
      DEFAULT_REGION: 'eu-central-1'
      DATA_DIR: /tmp/localstack/data
      HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL: localhost
      HOSTNAME: localstack
```

From gitlab-ci

```
do aws s3api head-bucket --bucket test-bucket --endpoint http://localhost:4566 && echo "Success" && break
```

Everything was working fine before but somehow it stopped working and it say Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4566/"

In the docker-compose file when I change the image to some backward version
`image: localstack/localstack:1.2.0`, it connect successfully.

I want to know if something is changed in the new image and do I need to change something at my end.

Comment: What's the last version that works for you? As in: can you figure out which version is causing the error?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Version 1.2.0 is working. If I go with version 1.3, 1.3.0 and 1.3.1 these one's are not working. I am ok with using 1.2.0 version. But I am curious to know what's get wrong by using the latest versions.